# why am I getting an error of local variable when I have declared it as a global variable, whilst trying to program a stack in python?

Tags: python, variables, stack, global, local

I keep getting the following error message:

> if stack_pointer < max_length: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'stack_pointer' referenced before assignment

I'm trying to program a stack data structure in python.

Here is my code:

```
stack_pointer = -1
stack =[]
max_length = 10

def view():
        for x in range (len(stack)):
            print(stack[x])
def push():
    if stack_pointer < max_length:
    item = input("Please enter the  item you wishto add to the stack: ")
    stack[stack_pointer].append(item)
    stack_pointer = stack_pointer + 1 
else:
     print("Maximum stack length reached!")

def pop():
    if stack_pointer < 0:
        print ("stack is empty!")
    else:
        item = stack[stack_pointer].pop(-1)
        stack_pointer = stackpointer - 1
        print ("you just popped out: ", item)

while True:
print ("")
print("Python implementation of a stack")
print("********************************")
print("1. view Stack")
print("2. Push onto Stack")
print("3. Pop out of Stack")
print("********************************")
print("")
menu_choice = int (input("Please enter your menu choice: "))
print ("")
print ("")

if menu_choice == 1:
    view()
elif menu_choice == 2:
    push()
elif menu_choice == 3:
    pop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to declare the variable global in functions where you change it.

For example:

```
def pop():
    global stack_pointer    # this is what you forgot
    if stack_pointer < 0:
        print ("stack is empty!")
    else:
        item = stack[stack_pointer].pop(-1)
        stack_pointer = stack_pointer - 1    # was a missing underscore here
        print ("you just popped out: ", item)
```

Variables in functions, if you assign to them, are considered local unless declared global (or nonlocal in Python 3).

Comment: Thanks, i've just got it to work but i've had to do: stack = [stack_pointer] what does this piece of code mean?

Comment: @lisaturner: `stack = [stack_pointer]` is almost certainly wrong. You're discarding the `stack`, and replacing it with a whole new `list` that contains the stack pointer, but none of the stack contents.

Comment: Also, there is no need to pass `-1` to `list.pop`; it already pops from the end of the `list` by default, so passing it just slightly increases argument parsing overhead without changing behavior.

Comment: i've got the code working but I've written my code in python implementing a stack, it is pushing and popping following LIFO but when you view the list it prints it as:

1
2
3

showing the last item at the bottom, how can I make it show the last item at the top like a proper stack?